# Use same routing for subdomain as for simple domain request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I have a live server say www.test.com and a development server with subdomain, like dev.test.com, but I want the same routing for both.
I can not use routing for development server.

Is it possible to write some code in before filter in `ApplicationController`?

Comment: what do you mean by routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused here.

If the sub domain is same then you do not need to to do anything.
Just locate your development server (with sub-domain) with the Development App code.

In Rails, routing are defined after '/'.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. You're right. I just confused a bit. Thanks BTW.